# How to post a date object in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Following is my schema definition:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var StudentSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    family: String,
    created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Student', StudentSchema);
```

How do I have post it? because whatever value I post, it default value, that current time. I tried following two things:

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "family": "xyz",
    "created": "2016-12-12"
}

{
    "name": "abc",
    "family": "xyz",
    "created": "1467883104"
}
```

**In both the cases, it stored current time only. Not the one which I am passing.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your schema defines the field `created` as `Date` object. What you are trying to store, however, is a plain string. You have to pass a real [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instead:

```
{
    name: "abc",
    family: "xyz",
    created: new Date("2016-12-12")
}
```